# Save and load multiple textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to save and load multiple textfields and i know I am doing something wrong because when i add another textfield to the NSUserDefaults i have my textfields mixing up the data. for example textfield one will be saved as "0" and textfield 2 as "1", though when i leave the controller and go back into it, it suddenly changes text view one to "1" and text view 2 to something i previously typed.

This code works fine for saving and loading one textfield but messes up when i add another textfield.

```
[_textview setText:[defaults valueForKey:@"textfield_text"]];
[_textview setDelegate:self];

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:textField.text forKey:@"textfield_text"];
[defaults synchronize];}
```

Then when i try to add two textfields the error i explained above occurs.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:YES]; {
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[_textview setText:[defaults valueForKey:@"textfield_text"]];
[_textview setDelegate:self];


NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[_textview1 setText:[defaults1 valueForKey:@"textfield_text1"]];
[_textview1 setDelegate:self];   }}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:textField.text forKey:@"textfield_text"];
[defaults synchronize];}

 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing1:(UITextField *)textField1{

NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults1 setValue:textField1.text forKey:@"textfield_text1"];
[defaults1 synchronize];}
```

Comment: `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing1:(UITextField *)textField1`? I think that method is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is a delegate method used by `UITextField`. When you call `[_textview setDelegate:self]`, and `[_textview1 setDelegate:self]`, you're telling *both* text fields to call your `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method. The fact that you called one of the text fields `_textview1`, doesn't mean that Apple's `UITextField` code knows that you also implemented a method that you named `textFieldDidEndEditing1:`. It's a perfectly valid method, it's just never called by you or the text fields (as Larme pointed out in the comments).

You need to handle both text fields in your implementation of `textFieldDidEndEditing:`, so you have to figure out which one is calling the method, and therefore which user defaults entry to update. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [_textview setText:[defaults valueForKey:@"textfield_text"]];
    [_textview setDelegate:self];
    [_textview1 setText:[defaults valueForKey:@"textfield_text1"]];
    [_textview1 setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *defaultsKeyForTextField;
    if ([textField isEqual:_textview]) {
        defaultsKeyForTextField = @"textfield_text";
    } else {
        defaultsKeyForTextField = @"textfield_text1";
    }
    [defaults setValue:textField.text forKey:defaultsKeyForTextField];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

You might also want to investigate the target-action mechanisms in Cocoa Touch - these allow you to hook up each text field to its own individual action method, rather than using delegate methods, if that's what you need in your app.

Just a quick aside - it looks like you might be very new to iOS, and programming in general, so you might want to focus your efforts on learning Swift, rather than Objective C, as you'll find almost all the tutorials and guides from the last two years are written in Swift. If you've got a particular reason to be learning Objective C that's all good too, I love both languages, but Swift certainly seems friendlier and is where all the action is right now!

Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Thank you for the help however now i keep getting a error saying use of undeclared identifier defaults.

Comment: never mind i just needed to add

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; to textFieldDidEndEditing.

Answer (score 0):

All UITextFields will call "textFieldDidEndEditing" so you have to differentiate which textfield is being edited. E.g.:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   if (textField == textField1) {
      :
   } else if (textField == textField2) {
      :
   }
}
```

Comment: probably nicer to use a `switch` selection here rather than having nested `else if` - in case you have more than two anyway

Comment: If programming in Swift... which the above is not. For Objective C, have to use if-else.

Comment: even when using this method i can only seem to save and load textview or in your case textField1.